# Turbogears on bluehost

Tags: python, apache, cherrypy, turbogears

Has anyone successfully installed TurboGears or CherryPy on BlueHost?  There are listings on the web, but none of them are viable or the links to the scripts are broken.

However, Bluehost Tech support claims that some folks are running TurboGears successfully on their shared hosting.

Anyone who has a setup or knows how, to install TurboGears or CherryPy on Bluehost, will be very appreciated if he/she could share their know-how.

Alternatively, if anyone knows another pythonic method that can be installed on Bluehost is welcome to share it with me.

Many thanks,

DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from their website, bluehost supports using FastCGI.
In that case you can deploy your applications using **FLUP**

`flup.server.fcgi.WSGIServer` permits to mount any WSGI application (like TurboGears apps) and use them with fastcgi.